# Simple JavaScript game [Mastermind] issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am coding a simple JavaScript version of the classic boardgame [**"Mastermind"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29).

I have some (for sure fundamental) problems, 99% with JavaScript arrays and referencing their values or elements. These issues am I "solving" currently for quite long time, so I decided to ask.

---

#### Facts:

- my game pegs, and the game board at all is made in HTML table, pegs are implemented like this(a row contains 4 pegs and a td containing the results image):

  ```
  <td>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"
         onClick="changePegColor('0','0'); return false"
         onFocus="this.blur()">
          <img src="img/void.png" width=22 height=22  name="peg_0_0">
      </a>
  </td>
  ```
- my default array declaration looks this (showing both variants tried, none of them worked for me):

  ```
  var pegsAI = ['pegAI_0', 'pegAI_1', 'pegAI_2', 'pegAI_3'];
  var pegsAI = new Array('pegAI_0', 'pegAI_1', 'pegAI_2', 'pegAI_3');
  ```
- Setting AI's pegs, which is the player going to guess works this way (this is working, no problem with array):

  ```
  pegsAI[position] = Math.floor((Math.random() * possibleColorsNumber));
  ```

And here are my issues:

1. At the moment of clicking Submit button, there is a check if every peg in a row has a colour this way (this does neither work, nor throws an error in chrome F12):

   ```
   ...
   for (var position = 0; position <= 3; position++) {
       if (document["peg_" + currentRow + "_" + position].src === "img/void.png") {
               alert('Finish color picking!');
           return false;
       }
   }
   ...
   ```
2. After this check, there is function that should convert players pegs to numbers and save it to an array and there is probably a problem, because it doesn't work (array got `undefined` values in result):

   ```
   function convertToNumbers() {
       for (var position = 0; position <= 3; position++) {                                         //4 pegs in row, var 'position' declares peg's position
           if (document["peg_" + currentRow + "_" + position].src === possibleColors[index] ) {  //if a peg has an color (his img's src is equal to an element of array 'possibleColors', which contains possible img's src's), then ->
               pegsPlayer[position] = index;                                                       // -> then index of this color saves to pegsPlayer[] array
           }
       }
   }
   ```

---

#### ///added for explanation

my function for calculating score:

```
var goodPegPlayer = [false, false, false, false];
var goodPegAI = [false, false, false, false];

function calcSkore() {
convertToNumbers();
alert("array values" + pegsPlayer[0] + "_" + pegsPlayer[1] + "_" + pegsPlayer[2] + "_" + pegsPlayer[3]);
for (var position = 0; position <= 3; position++) {
    goodPegPlayer[position] = false;
    goodPegAI[position] = false; 
    if (pegsPlayer[position] === pegsAI[position]) {
        skoreBlack++;
        goodPegPlayer[position] = true;
        goodPegAI[position] = true;
    }
} 

for (var position = 0; position <= 3; position++) {
    if (goodPegPlayer[position] === false) {
        for (var positionAI = 0; positionAI <= 3; positionAI++) {
            if ((position !== positionAI) && (goodPegPlayer[position] === false) && (goodPegAI[positionAI] === false)) {
                if (pegsPlayer[position] === pegsAI[positionAI]) {
                    skoreWhite++;
                    goodPegPlayer[position] = true;
                    goodPegAI[positionAI] = true;
                }
            }
        }
   }
}

resultsSubmit();

}
```

!! right after using converToNumber() function in this function, an alert() is used to check if the values are correct.

Comment: @cept0: I have restored the link, but selected one from Wikipedia instead. That maintains the usefulness of the link without promoting a commercial site.

Answer (score 1):

You're not accessing the DOM correctly. Try using the `id` attribute instead of `name` to identify your images and update your JavaScript as follows:

```
for (var position = 0; position <= 3; position++) {
    var id = "peg_" + currentRow + "_" + position;
    if (document.getElementById(id).src === "img/void.png") {
            alert('Finish color picking!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i changed it, but it didnt change nothing, still the same issue/ and alert() says still only the values I gave the elements when declaring.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own version of Mastermind back in 2004.

The code is a bit outdated, but it still works in modern browsers. I'm not sure if it's helpful to you, but feel free to take a look!

The code is MIT licensed, which means you can freely use it (or parts of it) anywhere you want!

---

#### Resources

- [**Demo**](http://jslegers.github.io/mastermind/)
- [**Github repository**](https://github.com/jslegers/mastermind)

[image]